# iText - detect missing EOF marker in PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, eof

I need to detect if a PDF file is missing the required `%%EOF` at the end.
I know that I could parse the content of the file to find the last line and test if it equals `%%EOF`, but is there any better method by using the iText API ?

I tried to call `PDFReader.getEofPos()` which should return the byte address of the `%%EOF` marker as it is written in the javadoc.

But even if there is no `%%EOF` marker this method seems to return the byte adress of the last character in the file.

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("./malformed.pdf");
//Returns something even if there is no %%EOF marker
System.out.println("EOF position: " + pdfReader.getEofPos());
```

Comment: If you need to test for the *`%%EOF` at the end*, you had better not use iText's information as iText tries to emulate some laxness also present in Adobe Reader. Instead you had better read an end segment of the file and check it, being as strict or as lax as you are required..